# State of existing resources without importing

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to inspect the state of existing resources without importing them into your state?

Currently I'm setting up GCP resources in a throw away project and then importing it into a throw away TF file, then inspecting the state of the resource and creating my final resource in my prod files from that base.

Is it possible to get the state of an resource that hasn't been imported?

Update:
Now that I've gained a lot more experience with TF I can confidently use the documentation to produce the desired outcomes.
Starting out in TF and in GCP itself it was a much simpler process for me to configure a component in the console and then inspect it and then iterate from there.
Data sources was very helpful and then became a required skill for passing info between TF deployments, so thank you for that suggestion.
Now a year on I understand the structure enough to work from the documentation to implement new features straight into my deployments.

Comment: You can use data sources to query existing resources.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: There are resources (used to create stuff from scratch) and data sources (used to get information about stuff that already exists). More info: https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got well your question, because while reading it I have only one thing in my mind "WHY?"

Terraform is meant for idempotency. All is meant to be replacable, reproductible, not copyable (or mockable).

So by default, there is no concept of "throw away" and "final" resources (actually it is a shoot in your foot and go in a way where Terraform is not meant for...)
You have the concept of workspaces, where you could have a test state to confirm all is good as you want. And then use the same code (with differents variables/configs if you want) where you could create the production resources.

IMHO, there is no reason to do it the "hard way"...

[Terraform workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces)